# Yarn workspaces and baseUrl in a shared package

Tags: webpack, yarn-workspaces

I've set up a monorepo with yarn workspaces. Thus far it's structure is similar to:

```
/packages
  /app1 <-- CRA
  /common
    Component1.js
    Component2.js
    jsconfig.json
```

I would like to create an absolute reference in Component1 to Component2. In other words, instead of `import thing from ./Component2`, I would like to write `import thing from Component2`. Thus, I have in my `jsconfig.json` in `common`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
  }
}
```

However, when I run `yarn --cwd packages/app1 start`, I get a compile error telling me Component2 can't be found.

So, how can I get `baseUrl` recognized by webpack in the referenced package?